# Using collect in send with different parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class called Trial which `has_many` results. Now What I want to do is some calculating with differend rows.

So I have an Array with all the collumn names that should be collected. And I want to use the Collect method but Its kind of tricky.

```
t = Trial.find(<id>)
["collumn1", "collunn2", "collumn3"].each do |collumn_name|
  data = t.results.send("collect", &:collumn_name)
  # HERE I WANT DO WORK WITH THE COLLECTED DATA
end
```

But it doesnt work because the collect method excepts some block not String. How can I deal with this Problem?

Comment: be aware that it's spelled `column`, not `collumn`

Comment: lol I dont think thats gonna crush the project^^ but thx

Comment: well, it won't crush Rails  bit it may crush the human readers' eyes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbol#to_proc will give you what you want:

```
t = Trial.includes(:results).find(<id>) # <-- use includes to avoid having to requery for results
[:collumn1, :collunn2, :collumn3].each do |collumn_name|
  data = t.results.collect &collumn_name
  # whatevs
end
```